# Delete all events in phone when uninstall the app from iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am making an application of reminders.For reminder, i am using events. When i am uninstalled the application.the events does not delete. I want to delete all event related to app when application is uninstalled. Plz help.

Comment: There is no api in iOS sdk that can handle app deinstallation.

Comment: Any other alternate?